# Why am I unable to select checkboxes in the AWS Cognito console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

AWS noob here, I want to manage my sign in options for user pools but everything is locked somehow. I've been struggling with this way too long trying to enable this but can't figure it out. I'm logged in as the root user. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot change the attributes of a Cognito User Pool (CUP) after it has been created.**

This restriction applies no matter how you create the user pool.

Instead, set up a new user pool & specify different attributes at *creation* time.

This is an AWS limitation that you can’t bypass, at least as of now.

---

From [AWS Premium Support Knowledge Center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-change-user-pool-attributes/):

> You can't change standard user pool attributes after a user pool is created.